# Connecting to Mac share after sleep

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, sharing, ventura

I am upgrading from an old iMac with macOS Monterey to a new Mac Mini with Studio Display and macOS Ventura.

On my new system I have both ethernet and wifi enabled, and file sharing for a number of folders. After the Mini has gone to sleep, I find that I can connect my iPad to the IP address for wifi, but not to the IP address for ethernet. Among other things, the `.local` name appears to resolve to the ethernet address, so that’s annoying.

On my old iMac, I can connect to the ethernet address, so obviously something’s different.

How can I connect to the ethernet address after my Mini has gone to sleep?

Why? you may ask. I would like to know what settings I might have got wrong, and I may not always want the wifi turned on.